# Baby likes to play with the mobile screen while watching cartoons; how to disable touch?

Tags: touchscreen, sony-xperia

Device: Sony Xperia Z Ultra

Whenever baby is watching cartoons he likes to pick up the phone and his touch then stops the video or if he slides, it changes the app. How can I disable touch screen while the video is playing so even if he is playing with the screen the video keeps on going and nothing happens?

P.S: He probably thinks I have to burst these guys too, just like he does on bubble burst type games. He is 8 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many devices have this feature included. When the video starts you can push the power button, and if your device supports it the video will play while the touch is turned off. (this is only for supported devices.)

The use of third party apps is what most use. **Untouch** is a very popular one, and can be found in the play store. ( search for Untouch or touch block and it should come up.)

You can also search XDA forums for touch block, I believe it's for sony devices.

Edit: Supported devices that I'm aware of, that support the no touch when video playback. These are the Samsung Galaxy S, and the Samsung Galaxy S2. Although you cannot use the feature with YouTube, and possibly other apps.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you provide sample device for the mentioned feature?

Comment: Notouch is another app that disable touch. You can even lock it with a password of your choice. Search for Notouch in Google Playstore

Answer (score 2):

You can use MX Player ([adware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) or [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro)), which has a "Kids lock" feature under
`Settings > Player > Controls > Lock mode`.

P.S. you should not give your phone to 8 months old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately its required for specially youtube, cant use any specific player. Was looking for a general solution. And oh i dont give him phone unsupervised. Its usually in my hands he just tries to grab it :) And when im not there he cant have it.